# Isn't the [grammar] tag too general or redundant?

Tags: discussion, tags

Here is the tag wiki of the [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag:

> Particles, conjugations and endings for verbs and adjectives, and general sentence structure.

But don't we already have [particles](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particles) (with all the particle-specific one like [particle-ni](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ni), [particle-de](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-de) etc), [conjugations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjugations), [verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs), [adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjectives) and [sentence-structures](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structures) tags?

So, isn't this [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag actually redundant? Is there any kind of grammar questions that are tagged with this tag but are not covered by any of the more specialized tags?

Answer (score 3):

I have no strong opinion on whether [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag should be kept or removed.  (Honestly speaking, I do not look at tags when I read questions.)  However, even if all grammatical questions can be tagged by more specific tags, I do not think that that means that we should remove the general tag.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave this in for people who know what particles are or as the default fall back tag for new comers to use.

Comment: But should regular members edit newcomers' questions to remove this tag and replace with specific ones?

Comment: @Lukman The more specific ones can be added, but I don't think the general one should be removed.  There are people following that tag as a catch-all for finding grammar-related questions and completely removing it means they'd have to track a dozen more specific tags instead (including ones that may not have been created yet).  It's not like we're filling up the existing tag slots right now.